# How to define nested array to ingest data and convert?

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, parquet, aws-glue, amazon-kinesis-firehose

I am using Firehose and Glue to ingest data and convert JSON to the parquet file in S3.

I was successful to achieve it with normal JSON (not nested or array). But I am failed for a nested JSON array. What I have done:

the JSON structure

```
{
    "class_id": "test0001",
    "students": [{
        "student_id": "xxxx",
        "student_name": "AAAABBBCCC",
        "student_gpa": 123
    }]
}
```

the Glue schema

1. class_id : string
2. students : array `ARRAY<STRUCT<student_id:STRING,student_name:STRING,student_gpa:INT>>`

I receive error:

```
The schema is invalid. Error parsing the schema: Error: type expected at the position 0 of 'ARRAY<STRUCT<student_id:STRING,student_name:STRING,student_gpa:INT>>' but 'ARRAY' is found.
```

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: Write custom classifier for JSON. Check https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/custom-classifier.html#custom-classifier-json for details

Comment: Any solution @franco phong ?

Answer (score 11):

I ran into that because I created schemas manually in the AWS console. The problem is, that it shows some help text next to form to enter your nested data which capitalizes everything, but Parquet can only work with **lowercase** definitions.

Write despite the example given by AWS:

```
array<struct<student_id:string,student_name:string,student_gpa:int>>
```

Comment: I just spent hours banging my head because of this.... thanks!